# Django error creating new content types

Tags: django, postgresql

I got this error when trying to move my dev db to production. Django dumpdata and loaddata were not sufficient so I was trying to make postgresql's pg_dump into a .sql file and then dropping the production database and creating a new one with the command

```
sql create database dbname;
sql dbname < dumpfile.sql
```

The site now shows up on my production server (with some missing css sheets) and the data is in the database. I couldn't figure out why some css sheets are not displaying (they are on the server) and when I tried to run manage.py migrate on my server then I got this traceback...

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: contenttypes
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 165, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(created_models, self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 268, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    using=db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 198, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 83, in create_permissions
    ctype = ContentType.objects.db_manager(using).get_for_model(klass)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 58, in get_for_model
    " is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually."
RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually
```

Have done some searching and couldn't find the answer to this, and I don't know where to turn to next.

Comment: can you try doing migrations on content type first? `python manage.py migrate contenttypes`. then you can try to do rest of the migrations - `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I still get the same error when I try that

Comment: sorry. cant think of anything else. hopefully somebody else will have an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to have something to do with migrations I am not quite sure how it works, but my dev version has a different set of migrations than my production (I think this is normal, not completely sure??)

so what I had to do in this case was drop the old db, create the new db, run manage.py migrate from the production server, and then input the dumped dbdata, and everything worked out fine.